# Why background image is not loading after browser refresh?

Tags: html, css

I have a background image set for the web app first time its working good but when i refresh browser its not loading.Another behaviour i noticed chrome its working good but IE is having issue.Any idea why its happening ?

```
body {
    /*background: #fafafa;*/
    background: url('../images/home.gif') no-repeat 0 0;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #333;
}
```

Comment: Refresh twice. Kinda odd, but it always does the trick for me (Firefox).

Comment: Or try a hard refresh, CTRL+F5

Comment: I'm guessing IE is caching the image, so yeah, CTRL + F5 or [Right Click] => [Shift] + [Refresh] does it as well. Is your problem that the file isn't loading at all? Because its possible IE doesn't know where  to look (because IE works a little differently from Chrome).

Comment: CTRL + F5 refresh is getting same result is not working and file is loading i checked that..

Comment: Open de image directly, eg: `example.com/images/home.gif and repeat. If still no results, you probably forgot to upload it

Comment: Did you had a look in the IE developer tools (F12) to see if the image file is loaded correctly? Watch for the HTTP status code of that image. Maybe there's a network problem, or something else.

Comment: Here you go getting closer i think i saw the error in network 304 but why url  is correct.

Comment: I am not sure why i am getting 304 everything is correct. Any solution ?

Comment: Its a local image, try taking out the quotes '' ie (url(../images/home.gif)

Comment: thanks for the help but without quotes its still not working..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From comments I could understand browser is caching image, HTTP status 304 confirms it.
Use backgroud image url appended with some query param with version (random)number. This prevents browser from aggressive caching

```
url('../images/home.gif?v=0')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<body style="background-image: url('https://*****/images/bg-01.jpg'); background-size: 100%;">
```

> Try this